# Ordering dictionary values on Jinja2 template

Tags: python, html, templates, dictionary, jinja2

I am using a Jinja2 template to render information to a report. I am creating a table showing the max, total, avg_size and avg_rate for certain types of events occuring on the system.

My code creates a new row after every 6 entries, and prints data that looks correct however on closer inspection it's not printing the data in the correct order because I'm using 'if' statements.

Is there away I can make `key2=='max_count'` always the first to print it's value, then `key2 == 'total'` and etc.

The order I want:

```
max_count, total, avg_size, avg_rate
```

Here is the part of my code causing the issue:

```
{% for key2, value2 in max_min_data[key].iteritems() %}  
  {% if count == 6 %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
    {% set count = 0 %}
  {% endif %} 
  {% if key2 == 'max_count'%}
    <td style="text-align: center; width:3.1in;">{{ '{0:,}'.format(value2['max']) }}</td>
  {% endif %}
  {% if key2 == 'total'%}
    <td style="text-align: center; width:3.1in;">{{'{0:,}'.format(value2['max'])}}</td>
  {% endif %}
  {% if key2 == 'avg_size'%}
    <td style="text-align: center; width:3.1in;">{{'{0:,}'.format(value2['max'])}}</td>
  {% endif %}
  {% if key2 == 'avg_rate'%}
    <td style="text-align: center; width:3.1in;">{{'{0:,}'.format(value2['max'])}}</td>
  {% endif %}
  {% set count = count + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

Example of dictionary I am looping through:

```
{
    'Event1': {
        'avg_rate': {'max': 11004, 'min': 0},
        'avg_size': {'max': 219, 'min': 218},
        'total': {'max': 107743, 'min': 103354},
        'max_count': {'max': 103756, 'min': 103094}
    },
    'Event2': {
        'avg_rate': {'max': 558, 'min': 0},
        'avg_size': {'max': 321, 'min': 319},
        'total': {'max': 11029, 'min': 10046},
        'max_count': {'max': 17724, 'min': 17585}
    },
    'Event3': {
        'avg_rate': {'max': 1824, 'min': 0},
        'avg_size': {'max': 363, 'min': 360},
        'total': {'max': 48737, 'min': 46529},
        'max_count': {'max': 47094, 'min': 46711}
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the data you're looping over?

Comment: @NilsWerner I have posted a example of the dictionary I'm looping through

Comment: Next time please also format the dict so people can read it (did that for you). You seem to be using two loops to traverse the dict, can you post more context and the desired output?

Comment: @NilsWerner As I am using 'if' statements in my Jinja template the order it is appearing in my report is 'avg_rate','avg_size','total','max_count' as that is the order it is in the dictionary. 
My question is how to I make the order in the Jinja template not dependant on the order in the dictionary but only takes into account order I have stated in my question above.

Comment: The code as it currently stands creates rows like `avg_rate | avg_size | total | max_count | avg_rate | avg_size --- total | max_count | avg_rate | avg_size ...` mixing columns from two events. Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a far simpler solution than I thought. I changed my Jinja2 template to the following and this solved the issue for me:

```
{% for key2, value2 in max_min_data[key].iteritems() %}  

  <td style="text-align: center; width:3.1in;">{{ '{0:,}'.format(value['max_count']['max']) }}</td>
  <td style="text-align: center; width:3.1in;">{{'{0:,}'.format(value['total']['max'])}}</td>
  <td style="text-align: center; width:3.1in;">{{'{0:,}'.format(value['avg_size']['max'])}}</td>
  <td style="text-align: center; width:3.1in;">{{'{0:,}'.format(value['avg_rate']['max'])}}</td>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I don't like this solution because of lots of repeated text.